# Naudio sound normalize

Tags: c#, arrays, byte, naudio

I am using Naudio and I have a stream which I need to read as array and then when I have found maximum I need to multiply each value with ( 1/ biggest ) and then I should have values in my array as [-1,1].

Comment: you know that the type byte does not support negative numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see really what you mean by "convert", but instead of the code you wrote you could just do:

```
var bytes = stream.ToArray();
var biggest = (float)bytes.Max();
var floats = bytes.Select(b => b / biggest).ToArray();
```

This will result with floats between 0 and 1, since bytes are always positive.

Answer (score 0):

**float to short:**

float num1;
short num6 = (short)num1;

http://www.convertdatatypes.com/Convert-short-to-byte-in-CSharp.html

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/convert-long-short-single-to-byte-array-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: Please include more details (Agreed you can't add commenta but don't write answers which are more like comments)